# Why do we need two normalization instances

Tags: python, keras, transformer-model

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

class TransformerEncoder(layers.Layer):
   # This is a custom layer that inherits from keras.layers.Layer, used to implement the encoder part of a Transformer model. This class uses the multi-head attention mechanism.

   def __init__(self, embed_dim, dense_dim, num_heads, **kwargs):
       super().__init__(**kwargs)
       self.embed_dim = embed_dim  # The dimension of the input embeddings.
       self.dense_dim = dense_dim  # The dimension of the dense layer in the feedforward network.
       self.num_heads = num_heads  # The number of heads in the multi-head attention mechanism.
       self.attention = layers.MultiHeadAttention(
           num_heads=num_heads, key_dim=embed_dim)  # A MultiHeadAttention instance for calculating attention weights.
       self.dense_proj = keras.Sequential(
           [layers.Dense(dense_dim, activation="relu"),  # The output dimension is dense_dim, and the input dimension is automatically matched.
            layers.Dense(embed_dim),]
       )  # A Sequential model containing two Dense layers for processing attention outputs.
       self.layernorm_1 = layers.LayerNormalization()  # A LayerNormalization layer for normalizing the input data.
       self.layernorm_2 = layers.LayerNormalization()  # Another LayerNormalization layer for normalizing the output after the feedforward network.

   def call(self, inputs, mask=None):
       # This method accepts two parameters: inputs (input data) and mask (an optional mask). The mask is usually used to indicate which positions in the sequence should be ignored, such as when dealing with padded sequences.

       if mask is not None:
           mask = mask[:, tf.newaxis, :]  # Expand the shape of the mask tensor from (batch_size, sequence_length) to (batch_size, 1, sequence_length).

       attention_output = self.attention(inputs, inputs, attention_mask=mask)  # Calculate attention weights using the MultiHeadAttention layer.

       proj_input = self.layernorm_1(inputs + attention_output)  # Normalize the sum of inputs and attention_output using the LayerNormalization layer.

       proj_output = self.dense_proj(proj_input)  # Process the normalized input through the feedforward network.

       return self.layernorm_2(proj_input + proj_output)  # Normalize the sum of proj_input and proj_output using another LayerNormalization layer.

   def get_config(self):
       # This method returns a dictionary containing the configuration of the layer, including the layer's type, parameters, weights, etc. When you use model.save() to save the model, Keras uses this configuration information to reconstruct the model's structure.

       config = super().get_config()  # First, call the parent class's get_config method to get a dictionary containing the parent class's configuration.

       config.update({
           "embed_dim": self.embed_dim,
           "num_heads": self.num_heads,
           "dense_dim": self.dense_dim,
       })
       return config  # Then, update the dictionary with the configuration information specific to this layer (embed_dim, num_heads, and dense_dim). This ensures that the custom layer's specific configuration is saved when saving the model.
```

The above is from Deep Learning with Python Second Edition by FrancoisChollet
Code snippet about implementing Transformer encoders as Layer subclasses;
My problem is this: I don't understand the need to instantiate two normalization layers specifically (see figure 2 for an indication); They're clearly the same
([Figure 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjObD.png)).

i didn't try anything because i just wanna figure out why the code author do this.

Comment: They are not the same, each of those layers have weights.

Comment: But it looks like tier normalization is just going to calculate the mean and variance of each tier and then do calculations on each tier, and it doesn't look like it keeps corresponding weights

Comment: I think you're correct @lizijing - normalization layers do not have weights

Comment: They do have weights, just check the implementation, as I said in my first comment: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/v3.0.2/keras/layers/normalization/layer_normalization.py#L154

Comment: @lizijing Not sure where you are looking, the implementation does have weights.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are correct that technically only one normalization layer is needed (it just will be used twice).

However, it's generally good practice to make a new layer for each "step" in your pipeline so that if things go wrong it's clear at what step they went wrong. I believe that's why the author created two different properties for essentially the same operation.

Comment: This is incorrect, LayerNormalization layers do have weights, just check the code: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/v3.0.2/keras/layers/normalization/layer_normalization.py#L154

Comment: yes,it is my fault ,layer normalization do have weight (but it is opt.).here are details from tensorflow "https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/LayerNormalization":"If scale or center are enabled, the layer will scale the normalized outputs by broadcasting them with a trainable variable gamma, and center the outputs by broadcasting with a trainable variable beta. gamma will default to a ones tensor and beta will default to a zeros tensor, so that centering and scaling are no-ops before training has begun.

"

Comment: Oh interesting, then I think you have your answer! Feel free to create your own answer and ping me and I'll upvote it (eventually - I don't check this site super often)